# How to efficiently check if a matrix is in binary form (e.g. all 1's or 0's)?

Tags: r, matrix

I have a function that take an m x n sized (potentially) binary matrix as input, and I would like to return an error handling if the matrix contains a number that is not 0 or 1, or is NA. How can I check this efficiently?

For instance, by generating some data for a 10 x 10:

```
> n=10;m=10
> mat = round(matrix(runif(m*n), m, n))
> mat
        [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
 [1,]    0    1    0    1    1    0    1    0    1     0
 [2,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     1
 [3,]    1    1    0    1    1    0    0    1    1     0
 [4,]    1    1    1    1    0    1    0    0    1     1
 [5,]    1    1    1    0    0    1    1    1    0     1
 [6,]    1    0    1    0    0    0    0    1    0     0
 [7,]    0    0    0    1    0    1    1    1    1     0
 [8,]    0    0    0    1    0    1    1    1    1     1
 [9,]    0    0    1    1    0    1    1    1    1     1
[10,]    1    0    1    1    0    0    0    0    1     1
```

should always return that the matrix is binary, but changing it in one of the following ways:

```
> mat[1,1]=NA
> mat[1,1]=2
```

should return that the matrix is not binary.

Currently, I have been using in my function:

```
for(i in 1:nrow(mat))
{
    for(j in 1:ncol(mat))
    {
      if(is.na(mat[i,j])|(!(mat[i,j] == 1 | mat[i,j] == 0)))
      {
        stop("Data must be only 0s, 1s")
      }
    }
}
```

but it seems awfully slow and inefficient to individually check every value for large matrices. Is there a clever, easy way to do this I'm missing?

Thanks

Comment: A guaranteed way to get a lot of responses is ask for something to be done faster in R ;)

Comment: @SeñorO  "'cause he's going the *distance*, he's going for **speed**,..."   :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I immediately thought of `identical(mat,matrix(as.numeric(as.logical(mat),nr=nrow(mat)) ) )`

This leaves `NA` as `NA` so if you want to identify the existence of such, you'll just need a quick `any(is.na(mat))` or similar test.

EDIT:  time trial

```
fun2 <- function(x) {
      all(x %in% 0:1)
}
fun1 <-function(x) {identical(as.vector(x),as.numeric(as.logical(x)))}

mfoo<-matrix(sample(0:10,1e6,rep=TRUE),1e3)
 microbenchmark(fun1(mfoo),fun2(mfoo),is.binary.sum2(mfoo),times=10)
Unit: milliseconds
                 expr       min        lq    median        uq
           fun1(mfoo)  2.286941  2.809926  2.835584  2.865518
           fun2(mfoo) 20.369075 20.894627 21.100528 21.226464
 is.binary.sum2(mfoo) 11.394503 12.418238 12.431922 12.458436
       max neval
  2.920253    10
 21.407777    10
 28.316492    10
```

And against the `not...` thing: I had to throw in a `try` to avoid breaking the test.

```
notfun <- function(mat) try(stopifnot(sum(mat==0) + sum(mat==1) == length(mat)))
 microbenchmark(fun1(mfoo),notfun(mfoo),is.binary.sum2(mfoo),times=10)
Error : sum(mat == 0) + sum(mat == 1) == length(mat) is not TRUE
##error repeated 10x for the 10 trials
Unit: milliseconds
                 expr       min        lq    median        uq
           fun1(mfoo)  4.870653  4.978414  5.057524  5.268344
         notfun(mfoo) 18.149273 18.685942 18.942518 19.241856
 is.binary.sum2(mfoo) 11.428713 12.145842 12.516165 12.605111
       max neval
  5.438111    10
 34.826230    10
 13.090465    10
```

I win!  :-)

Comment: IMHO it doesn't work: `identical(c(1L, 0L), as.logical(c(1L, 0L)))` (to convert the matrix into an integer vector creates false positives: `identical(as.integer(c(1.1, 0)), as.integer(as.logical(c(1.1, 0))))`)

Comment: @sgibb -- wait, I think I fixed it:  `as.numeric(as.logical(mat))` seems OK to me.

Comment: @Carl Excellent! This is clear, concise, efficient, and appears to work properly in any cases. Thanks!

Comment: @CarlWitthoft: Yes, great! I really like this simple and clear solution!

Answer (score 5):

Here are timings for a few options (including options suggested in other answers):

```
n=5000;m=5000
mat = round(matrix(runif(m*n), m, n))
> system.time(stopifnot(sum(mat==0) + sum(mat==1) == length(mat)))
   user  system elapsed 
   0.30    0.02    0.31 
> system.time(stopifnot(all(mat %in% c(0,1))))
   user  system elapsed 
   0.58    0.06    0.63 
> system.time(stopifnot(all(mat==0 | mat==1)))
   user  system elapsed 
   0.77    0.03    0.80
```

They're all pretty fast, considering it's a 5000 by 5000 matrix! The fastest of the three seems to be:

```
stopifnot(sum(mat==0) + sum(mat==1) == length(mat))
```

Comment: The first and the third might be derailed by NAs though

Comment: Indeed, the first one is easily fixed by adding `na.rm=T` as an argument to the two `sum` functions, and still appears to be the fastest of the three with that addition. Thanks for the solution!

Comment: All three options work correctly in R 3.0.1 when an NA is inserted into the matrix.

Answer (score 5):

I like to add a slightly modified version of the `sum` based comparison that is faster than @JamesTrimble's version. I hope all my assumptions are correct:

```
is.binary.sum2 <- function(x) {
  identical(sum(abs(x)) - sum(x == 1), 0)
}
```

Here the benchmark:

```
library(rbenchmark)

n=5000
m=5000
mat = round(matrix(runif(m*n), m, n))

is.binary.sum <- function(x) {
  sum(x == 0) + sum(x == 1) == length(x)
}

is.binary.sum2 <- function(x) {
  identical(sum(abs(x)) - sum(x == 1), 0)
}

is.binary.all <- function(x) {
  all(x == 0 | x == 1)
}

is.binary.in <- function(x) {
  all(x %in% c(0, 1))
}

benchmark(is.binary.sum(mat), is.binary.sum2(mat),
          is.binary.all(mat), is.binary.in(mat),
          order="relative", replications=10)
#                 test replications elapsed relative user.self sys.self user.child sys.child
#2 is.binary.sum2(mat)           10   4.635    1.000     3.872    0.744          0         0
#1  is.binary.sum(mat)           10   7.097    1.531     6.565    0.512          0         0
#4   is.binary.in(mat)           10  10.359    2.235     9.216    1.108          0         0
#3  is.binary.all(mat)           10  12.565    2.711    11.753    0.772          0         0
```

Answer (score 4):

A quite efficient (and *readable*) way could be

```
all(mat %in% c(0,1))
```

However as pointed out it may not be the most fast, if compared to other solutions.

But, to add a few, if **efficiency** is a must (eg you do this test a lot
of times) a **lot of gain** is given by working with `integer` matrix
(`double`s have more bytes) and check against `integer` values. 
This gain could also apply to other solutions as well. 
A few tests with `%in%`follow:

```
library(microbenchmark)
set.seed(1)

my.dim <- 1e04
n <- my.dim
m <- my.dim
mat <- round(matrix(runif(m*n), m, n))
int.mat <- as.integer(mat)

fun1 <- function(x) {
      all(x %in% c(0,1))
}
fun2 <- function(x) {
      all(x %in% 0:1)
}

## why?
storage.mode(0:1)
## [1] "integer"
storage.mode(c(0,1))
## [1] "double"
object.size(0:1)
## 48 bytes
object.size(c(0,1))
## 56 bytes
## and considering mat and int.mat
object.size(mat)
## 800000200 bytes
object.size(int.mat)
## 400000040 bytes

(res <- microbenchmark(fun1(mat), fun2(int.mat), times = 10, unit = "s"))
## Unit: seconds
##           expr     min      lq  median      uq     max neval
##      fun1(mat) 3.68843 3.69325 3.70433 3.72627 3.73041    10
##  fun2(int.mat) 1.28956 1.29157 1.32934 1.34370 1.35718    10
```

From 3.70 to 1.32 is **not** that bad :)

Answer (score 1):

Note, I changed a few things so it runs in `octave`, but it should be pretty similar to `matlab`.

Generate the matrix:

```
n=5000;m=5000
mat=randi([0,1],n,m);
```

Now we just do something simple, we know that `1*2-1` would make the `1` equal to `1`, while it makes `0` equal to `-1`. So, `abs` makes it all the same. For any other value, say `-1`, `-1*2-1=-3` this isn't the case. Then we subtract `1` and we should be left with a matrix with only zeros. This can be easily checked in matlab/octave with `any`:

```
any(any(abs(mat*2-1)-1));
```

Checking its speed:

```
mat=randi([0,1],n,m);
[t0 u0 s0]=cputime(); any(any(abs(mat+mat-1)-1)); [t1 u1 s1]=cputime(); [t1-t0 u1-u0 s1-s0]
ans =
 0.176772   0.127546   0.049226
```

In the order `total`, `user`, and `system` time.

Pretty decent under `0.18` seconds with most of it in user mode. With `10.000 * 10.000` entries it is still under a second, clocking in at `0.86` seconds on my system.

Oh, heck, I only now see it is actually asked for `R`, not `matlab`. I hope someone likes the comparison though.

Handling `NaN` values is easy in `octave`/`matlab` with `isnan(mat)`, eventually in the form of `any(any(isnan(mat)))` if you like. This includes `NA` values. Handling only `NA` values is through `isna(mat)`.

Comment: How does this handle `NA` values?

Comment: @CarlWitthoft, sorry Carl, I added it